# Slow application response with AAD Proxy and Application Gateway WAF

Tags: azure

We have published internal IIS application externally through combination of Azure AD Proxy and Application Gateway WAF (sku1). The connector is on a dedicated VM in another subnet peered to IIS server subnet. Azure AD proxy has "passthrough" authentication mode, and AG/WAF is set to Detection mode. Customer is complaining that the application has very slow response for external users. We have selected this combination primarily because WAF sku1 does not allow for static public IP.

Is it possible that using this combo introduces unnecessary lag/timeouts into traffic flow that is causing slow application response?

Is leaving just App Proxy with Passthrough auth safe enough ?

Thanks for any insights.

Michael

Basically the setup is as illustrated on this picture, except there is no AAD Auth.

[image]

Comment: You have several hops in your network and each of them will analyze network packets, which can add latency but you need metrics.

The best thing to do is to analyse the network latency and find the component causing the lag. I'm unfamiliar with App Proxy, but you can perform a network test from the connector and the App Gateway to the VM.